# Determine the exact path of a python imported package "mkl"

Tags: python, import

How can I determine  the exact path of a python imported package. In my case, it is

```
import mkl
```

I am on python3 with an anaconda3 environment.

Comment: What problem are you hoping to solve by finding out the path?

Comment: ＠Karl Knechtel I have the same problem. In my case, I have different versions of mkl installed in my computer, and want to figure out which one they are and where they are.